# resolving ts-loader in a path using webpack 2.2.1 in a script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, webpack-2

Given the following gulp task.
I get error output

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app.ts' in 'wwwroot/js/admin'

```
gulp.task("admin:js", function (done) {
    module.exports = {
        context: "wwwroot/js/admin",
        entry: ["app.ts", "zippy.ts"],
        output: {
            filename: "admin.js"
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        module: {
            rules: [
              { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
            ]
        }
    };
    webpack(module.exports).run(onBuild(done));
});
```

with directory structure

```
wwwroot\js\admin\app.ts
wwwroot\js\admin\zippy.ts
```

I am getting this error:

```
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 31ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    admin.js  2.87 kB       0  [emitted]  main
admin.js.map  2.61 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} admin.js, admin.js.map (main) 40 bytes [entry] [rendered]
    [0] multi app.ts zippy.ts 40 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in multi app.ts zippy.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app.ts' in 'wwwroot/js/admin'
 @ multi app.ts zippy.ts

ERROR in multi app.ts zippy.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zippy.ts' in 'wwwroot/js/admin'
 @ multi app.ts zippy.ts
```

It's a path issue, as if I execute `webpack` from the command line, in the `wwwroot\js\admin` directory, without the context path, the files get bundled correctly and it all works.

When I use the API script, and execute from the project root (relative to `.\wwwroot\js\admin`) I get the error output.

Comment: come on - is this question so stupid as to not even elicit a single comment after 14 hours... have I worded it badly... These paths are really frustrating me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack does **not support** the use of **relative paths** in the **`context`** configuration entry.

changing `context` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/wwwroot/js/admin",
    ...
```

corrected the output.

```
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 2337ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    admin.js  1.24 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
admin.js.map  1.48 MB       0  [emitted]         main
chunk    {0} admin.js, admin.js.map (main) 1.24 MB [entry] [rendered]
    [0] ./~/angular/index.js 48 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./wwwroot/js/admin/app.ts 408 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./wwwroot/js/admin/zippy.ts 1.16 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/angular/angular.js 1.24 MB {0} [built]
    [4] multi ./app.ts ./zippy.ts 40 bytes {0} [built]
[10:30:37] Finished 'admin:js' after 2.43 s
```